# Change Name field on lead object to auto-number - is this possible?

Tags: leads, auto-number, standard-field

I was trying to change the field type on the `lead` object to an auto-number but it doesn't seem I can as there is no option to do so - does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the types of standard fields, such as `Lead.Name`.

If you need to auto-populate a required standard field, such as this one, options to consider include Quick Actions with Predefined Field Values, and in some circumstances `before insert` Apex triggers.